# Brought over code from project where all tests are passing, but in the new project I'm getting an error. TypeError: provider.send is not a function

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

```
  1 failing

  1) pvp-amm
       Is initialized!:
     TypeError: provider.send is not a function
      at /home/tomdevito27/pvp-amm/tests/pvp-amm.ts:81:18
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (tests/pvp-amm.ts:28:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Heres my ts code

````
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { PvpAmm } from "../target/types/pvp_amm";
import * as assert from "assert";
import * as bs58 from "bs58";
import * as serumCmn from "@project-serum/common";
import { TokenInstructions } from  "@project-serum/serum";

describe("pvp-amm", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.PvpAmm as Program<PvpAmm>;

  let usdcMint = null;

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.

    usdcMint = await createMint(program.provider);

  });
const TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
  TokenInstructions.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toString()
);
async function createMint(provider, authority) {
  if (authority === undefined) {
    authority = provider.wallet.publicKey;
  }
  const mint = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const instructions = await createMintInstructions(
    provider,
    authority,
    mint.publicKey
  );

  const tx = new anchor.web3.Transaction();
  tx.add(...instructions);

  await provider.send(tx, [mint]);

  return mint.publicKey;
}

async function createMintInstructions(provider, authority, mint) {
  let instructions = [
    anchor.web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: mint,
      space: 82,
      lamports: await provider.connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(82),
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    TokenInstructions.initializeMint({
      mint,
      decimals: 9,
      mintAuthority: authority,
    }),
  ];
  return instructions;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the original code has

```
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(provider);
```

instead of

```
anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
```